# Anyway to run a meek bridge on a php hosting?

Tags: bridge, meek

Is it possible to use a common php hosting to run a meek bridge ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite meek in php.
But it's too complicated.
There is a simple way to run a relay, just function like a meek server.
Here are code:
https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git/tree/php/index.php